# Kernel Methods for Binary Vectors

Tags: binary-data, kernel-trick, distance-functions, similarities

I am currently involved in a project which requires a minor point in choosing a proper similarity metric for a set of binary vectors, i.e. all components are either 1 or 0.

Currently, the go-to approach is using an asymmetric jaccard similarity (excluding the number of both being zeros). I am wondering whether there is a better similarity measure for example, some kernel based similarity measure.

Comment: How do you plan to use this kernel? In any way, I'd go with Hamming distance - it's a proper distance, so it should correspond to a proper kernel